# I am making signup page and login page and I got some error

Tags: android, firebase

I am providing link of code. What might be the problem here?

https://cloud.degoo.com/share/BLKPJOLqE63cxN

Error shown:

> error: ')' expected
>
> ```
> Toast.makeText(AccountFragment.this, AccountFragment.this.toString()"SignUp Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> ```

Comment: Could you add your code (or the relevant part of the code) to the question itself? Code formatting tools are provided.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `AccountFragment.this.toString()` in line 59 and 62. The IDE even underlined those places in red.

Additionally, the first parameter in both `makeText` method calls have a wrong type. Call `getActivity` there in order to get a `Context`:

`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ...`

Comment: again error shown     https://cloud.degoo.com/share/jQZ9qVX1zteOCF     error ---- --- --  error: no suitable method found for makeText(AccountFragment,String,int)
                                Toast.makeText(AccountFragment.this,"SignUp Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     ^
    method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; AccountFragment cannot be converted to Context)
    method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; AccountFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: @Buddy I updated my answer.